# Can I ask a question to review an FAQ written on a third-party site?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, asking-questions, third-party

I wrote [an FAQ on a third-party website](http://tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7643) related to Delphi and thread-protection of objects. I need some feedback if this content is adequate or not. I was wondering can I ask a question on Code Review which references this third-party site, or would I have to re-create the content on Code Review?

I went ahead and asked a question anyway without any direct link to the original third-party FAQ:

[Is this the right way to thread-protect an object?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33427/is-this-faq-adequate-to-publish-or-is-anything-wrong-with-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow sites like this are exactly why I **only** use StackExchange sites. Don't you find us much better-looking? :)

I don't think it's a good idea to just link to that site. If you're talking about [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33427/is-this-faq-adequate-to-publish-or-is-anything-wrong-with-it) then I think you've done the right thing.

You see we like our stuff self-contained within SE (true on all sites), so it's VERY likely that your question will get put on hold and eventually closed, if all there is to it, is a link to that 3rd-party Delphi forum.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I write there is because I can't write the same in Stack Overflow or any of such sites.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it's on-topic either, CR is about *code* review, not for reviewing technical writings... Although I suppose your code *can* be reviewed.

Comment: Well the general concept of the topic is what I was aiming for. Not necessarily my grammar or anything like that.

Comment: I find it's a bit of a stretch. I'm going to *wait and see* on that one, but I wouldn't be too surprised to see close votes pile up. Don't worry if it gets put on hold, it isn't final - you can edit your post into a form that makes it look more like an actual piece of code you've written as part of a project, and less like a blog post.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised either, I'm not sure what questions are acceptable on Code Review. It just seemed the most appropriate site to ask it on, since it's reviewing code (and some code concepts)

Comment: Seen this? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The code in that is directly related to projects I've been working on. I wrote that as a common practice of mine. The text content around it is just explaining it, which is always good for any question. Code without explanation is definitely off-topic, but in this case the whole question is pertaining to the explanation of the code. The question is really aimed at my code, perhaps I didn't make it clear enough?

Comment: Edited my question on Code Review to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

make sure that your code works.

that should be first.

then take out all the explanation stuff, someone that is reviewing your code will most likely understand what you are talking about.

break it up into separate questions,  the post that you created is rather lengthy,  and ask if there is anything that can be improved in the code **and why or how**.  this will help you understand what is going on with the code without really going off topic (too far?).

Answer (score 2):

```
Can I ask a question to review an FAQ written on a third-party site?
```

**No you can not.**

See the site's policy on [Make sure you include your code in your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

And if you copy and paste content in order to be reviewed here, make sure the content in question is licence-able under the Creative Commons BY-SA 3 licence. See the very last line of text on this page.